# Unable to parse a phone number and an address

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

I've written a script in python to grab a phone number and an address from some elements. The thing is the way I've tried to parse the phone number is definitely messy. I can do the same for address. However, is there a cleaner or better way?

Elements within which the data is embedded:

```
html_content='''
    <div style="">
        <strong>Pamela Banchy, Chief Information Officer</strong>
            <br>Western Reserve Hospital<br> 
            <br>Lyndhurst, OH <br>
                <a href="mailto:pbanchy@westernreservehospital.org">pbanchy@westernreservehospital.org</a>
            <br>(330) 971-7456<br>
    </div>
    '''
```

Expression and script I've used to parse phone number:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

tree = fromstring(html_content)
phone = ' '.join([elem.text_content().strip().split()[-2] for elem in tree.cssselect("div")])
phone1 = ' '.join([elem.text_content().strip().split()[-1] for elem in tree.cssselect("div")])
print(phone+phone1)
```

Result:

```
(330)971-7456
```

By the way, the address is `Lyndhurst, OH` and the phone number is `(330)971-7456` which I've already grabbed in a messy way.

Comment: Do you have many similar tags to extract information from, or just this one?

Comment: Many similar br tags but the common thing is the phone number is in the last position and the address is in the third last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your text by newlines, so that you can fetch the address and phone number more conveniently with minimal post-processing.

```
for elem in tree.cssselect('div'):
    elem = elem.text_content().split('\n')
    address = elem[-4].strip()
    phone = elem[-2].replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: I'm gonna accept it as an answer cause you have showed me how to. I've got an idea to make it one liner. `address = ' '.join([elem.text_content().strip().split('\n')[-3] for elem in tree.cssselect("div")])` and 
`phone = ' '.join([elem.text_content().strip().split('\n')[-1] for elem in tree.cssselect("div")])`

Comment: @Shahin I wrote it as such because I assumed you wanted to extract the address and number from each div tag individually. Your one-liners will concatenate all the addresses together and all the phone numbers together. This is fine, if that's what you want. By the way, you may want to pay attention concatenating the addresses with a space, when the addresses themselves can contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks Reti43, for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do it:

```
text_nodes = [node for node in tree.cssselect('div')[0].itertext() if node.split()]
adress, phone = text_nodes[2], text_nodes[4]
```

Comment: This style is quite new to me sir. Yeah, it does the thing. Thanks sir.

Comment: Your solution is the best in this case. Only two lines of code can fetch 5 individual results. Thanks again sir.

Comment: Note that if you want to assign all 5 text nodes to 5 different variables, you can use syntax `name, work, address, email, phone = text_nodes`

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a more specific CSS selector. Instead of manipulating the value returned by `tree.cssselect("div")`, you can use

```
tree.cssselect("div > br:nth-child(3)")
```

which, when you access its text, should return "(330) 971-7456". The `>`'s access the elements of the parent, e.g. `div > br` selects all `<br>` elements where the parent is a `<div>` element, and "3" specifies the 3rd child of the  parent. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more details.

This will work in this simple case, but you might run into issues if there are multiple elements specified by `div > br:nth-child(3)`, say if there were 2 groups of `<div>`'s with `<br>`'s. In this case, the CSS selector should return multiple values (in a list or something) and you would want to loop over all of them and extract each phone number. *Disclaimer: I have not used the lxml.html library and I haven't researched what the expected function of cssselect() is, so no guarantees here.*

Comment: Your selector doesn't make any sense. Thanks for your try, though!

Comment: After looking at your HTML code a little more, I realized it also needs some clarification. For instance, `<br>HI THERE<br>` makes no sense on its own. It should be `<br>HI THERE</br>`. I edited my CSS selector after realizing the indentation was confusing. Please provide a clearer example!

Comment: I'm really confused to see your selector. How come you create a selector on basis of br tag. It's a line break.

Comment: Oh! I assumed since you're talking about HTML, that `<br>` was an element. As you may already know, HTML tags are surrounded by `<`'s and `>`'s. I believe the other user answer by Ilya also assumed this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that better way is using xpath.
`address, phone = tree.xpath('./div/br/text()')[-2:]`